# Installing CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia Quadro FX 580

Tags: 16.04, cuda

I have Nvidia Quadro FX 580 graphic card (quite old). When I checked `Additional Drivers` tab in `Software & Updates`, I only saw version `340.96`.

However, CUDA 7.5 somehow mentioned that it requires nvidia 355 at least to perform.

How could I install CUDA with this card?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Mine is Nvidia Quadro 1000M. I tried and got it working with Ubuntu 16.04. Documented it here: http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/